# Targeting child elements jquery

Tags: jquery, selector, addclass

this code should target child element of .refer class and assign to it .ref-hover, but it assign it just to .refer

simpled html:

```
<div class="refer left">

    <div class="desc box">

    <h3>Anticorro</h3>

    <p>Soundtrack</p>
    </div>

    <div class="video box">
        <iframe>soundcloud iframe</iframe>
     </div>
</div>
```

js here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.refer').hover(
    function () {
    $(this).children('.video').addClass('.ref-hover');
    }, function () {
    $(this).children('.video').removeClass('.ref-hover');
});

});
```

example: http://www.needles.cz (those blocks with soundcloud players)

wheres the problem?

Comment: Please post your HTML structure here, too. As soon as the problem is fixed, this question loses its validity and usefulness.

Comment: what is the children here

Comment: Switch to `.find()` instead of `.children()`

Comment: `children()` will only match the immediate child elements of `.refer`. You don't have any, so you need `find()`.

Comment: sorry guys, html uploaded...quite a newbie..as u prbbly realized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.refer').hover(
    function () {

    $(this).children('.video').addClass('ref-hover');
    }, function () {
    $(this).children('.video').removeClass('ref-hover');
});

});
```

Comment: strange, even with find function it still assign to a .refer class

Comment: @Andre Allin can u create a link

Comment: @Andre Allin i updated code .it is working for me.Check it once

Comment: @Andre Allin  i created link see here once it is working  http://jsfiddle.net/hwzEe/1/

Comment: @Andre Allin you are wel come